# Edit ruined my puzzle!

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

Unfortunately, I can't explain what happened without spoiling the puzzle, so only read on if you want a puzzle ruined for you.

> I considered a puzzle involving a fake sockpuppet answer [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5686/breaking-the-rules-for-a-purpose). I ended up posting this puzzle. It lives [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/46745/why-am-i-being-sued). But unfortunately the fake sockpuppet answer which was actually part of the puzzle was removed. It was a very low quality answer, and normally it would have made perfect sense to remove it. However, it was actually part of the puzzle, as were the comments on it. The person who removed it of course, could not know this. My question is, is there any way the answer, with its comments, could be brought back?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No.

> Just because it's part of the puzzle doesn't mean that quality standards don't apply. Answers must actually be attempts to answer the question.
>
> All mods were aware of its status as "part of the puzzle", but decided (with input from the community's *numerous* flags) that it should be judged just like any other answer. If the answer is edited to be an actual attempt at answering the question, it can be undeleted.

Comment: I see. Fair enough. It will make the puzzle better anyway.

Comment: So I fixed the answer. It might not be a "good" one, but I think it meets quality standards now

Comment: Also, if it does get reinstated, please make sure that the comments from John Doe and Richard Roe are also returned

Comment: @RichardRoe After your edits to the answer, I have undeleted it.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain thanks.